# How to exclude Rows from <xsl:for-each> only 'Maths' and 'Zulu' to exclude

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Can you please assist with displaying everything on the xsl:for-each but only Maths and Zulu to exclude
How to exclude Rows from xsl:for-each only 'Maths' and 'Zulu' to exclude. XSLT which displays everything at the moment. i the output should display everything but not Zulu and English.

```
<subjects_group>
    <subjects>
        <module>Maths</module>
    </subjects>
    <subjects>
        <module>Science</module>
    </subjects>
    <subjects>
        <module>Geography</module>
    </subjects>
    <subjects>
        <module>History</module>
    </subjects>
    <subjects>
        <module>Arts</module>
    </subjects>
    <subjects>
        <module>Life Orientation</module>
    </subjects>
    <subjects>
        <module>English</module>
    </subjects>
    <subjects>
        <module>Zulu</module>
    </subjects>
    <subjects>
        <module>Computer Studies</module>
    </subjects>
    <subjects>
        <module>Engineering</module>
    </subjects>
</subjects_group>
```

XSLT which displays everything at the moment. i the output should display everything but not Zulu and English.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:attribute-set name="font_styles">
        <xsl:attribute name="font-size">9pt</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-family">ArialNarrow</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="main_heading">
        <xsl:attribute name="color">rgb(241,90,34)</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="font-weight">bold</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="ligh_grey">
        <xsl:attribute name="background-color">#EEEEEE</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border">
        <xsl:attribute name="border-width">0.01mm</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="border-color">#999999</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="line-height">14pt</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_left" use-attribute-sets="border">
        <xsl:attribute name="border-left-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_right" use-attribute-sets="border">
        <xsl:attribute name="border-right-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_top" use-attribute-sets="border">
        <xsl:attribute name="border-top-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_bottom" use-attribute-sets="border">
        <xsl:attribute name="border-bottom-style">solid</xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:attribute-set>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_all" use-attribute-sets="border border_left border_right border_top border_bottom"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_cell" use-attribute-sets="border border_left border_top"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_cell_right" use-attribute-sets="border border_left border_top border_right"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_cell_bottom" use-attribute-sets="border border_left border_top border_bottom"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_cell_right_bottom" use-attribute-sets="border_all"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_top_right_bottom" use-attribute-sets="border border_top border_bottom border_right"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_right_bottom_left" use-attribute-sets="border border_left border_right border_bottom"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_top_right" use-attribute-sets="border border_top border_right"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_left_right" use-attribute-sets="border border_left border_right"/>
    <xsl:attribute-set name="border_top_bottom" use-attribute-sets="border border_top border_bottom"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root>
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="first" page-height="29.7cm" page-width="21cm">
                    <fo:region-body margin-bottom="10mm" margin-left="10mm" margin-right="10mm" margin-top="10mm"/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="first">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:table border-bottom-color="rgb(241,90,34)" border-bottom-style="solid" border-bottom-width="0.6mm">
                        <fo:table-column column-width="40mm"/>
                                        <fo:table-column column-width="149mm"/>
                                        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="/*/subjects"> 
                                            <fo:table-row>
                                                    <fo:table-cell>
                                                        <fo:block><xsl:value-of select="module"/></fo:block>
                                                    </fo:table-cell>
                                                </fo:table-row>
                                                </xsl:for-each>
                                        </fo:table-body>
                                    </fo:table>
            </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You forgot to add your XSLT that shows how you're trying to use xsl:for-each and also the example of the wanted output.

Comment: Hi, here is mt XSLT

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [predicate](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-10/#predicates) that tests the string value of the child `module`...

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="/*/subjects[not(module='Zulu') and not(module='English')]">
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

If you were able to use XSLT 2.0 or higher, it becomes a lot cleaner because you can use a sequence of strings...

```xml
<xsl:for-each select="/*/subjects[not(module=('Zulu','English'))]">
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: @Smooth - good to hear. Please consider accepting this answer by clicking the check mark next to it. Thanks!